# mex/c++ version of *by the book* level set methods?

Tags: performance, matlab, numerical, mex

Shot in the dark- does anyone know of a faster / mex / C / C++ version of level set methods and numerical hyperbolic PDEs?

I like this package a lot:
http://barissumengen.com/level_set_methods/index.html

but holy cow some things are unnecessarily slow! A gold star goes to someone with a faster version of level-sets and/or conservation-law PDE solvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered this face-to-face. Answer is:   http://ktchu.serendipityresearch.org/software/lsmlib/index.html